# Mapping a number to a interval using r

Tags: r, loops

Suppose i have a number **7010** and i want to map to which interval it belongs to. My intervals are as follows

```
int1 <- 5055:5127    
int2 <- 5256:5525    
int3 <- 5771:6046    
int4 <- 6621:6896    
int5 <- 6990:7106     
int6 <- 7548:7580
```

How to use loop and map to which interval my number **7010** belongs

Comment: Try using the `cut` function.

Comment: @Gopala i didnt get it

Comment: If you want to map values to ranges, you can use the cut function to generate the range column. Typing `?cut`? will help you. Someone suggested `findInterval` above. Perhaps that works for you. Not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @gopala find interval worked

Comment: @gopala the problem with the findInterval is that is will give interval even if it is not between intervals . for example i put **5129** it will show 2 interval however the result should be that is doesnot belong to any of these interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you stored your vectors in the global environment, we first retrieve them using `ls()` and a regex in the `pattern=` argument to match all objects starting with `int` and ending with a digit.

This will return a character string with all object names matched that we will pass to `mget()` in order to return the values of the named objects and store them in a list using `as.list()`

Finally, we iterate over the list using `lapply` to test which element contains `7010` using `%in%`:

```
lst <- as.list(mget(ls(pattern = "int[[:digit:]]")))
lapply(lst, function(x) 7010 %in% x)
```

Which gives:

```
$int1
[1] FALSE

$int2
[1] FALSE

$int3
[1] FALSE

$int4
[1] FALSE

$int5
[1] TRUE

$int6
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Nice one. I was trying to do the same with `paste0` but couldn't quite get there

Comment: @Steven can you please explain "int[[:digit:]]" . what should be substituted here

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA See added explanations

Answer (score 1):

May be `%in%`:

```
7010 %in%  6990:7106  
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the exact premises of your question. From the data you show I guess it should be applicable to (maybe signed) integer numbers of non-overlapping intervals, and you need to know if a given integer is in a given interval. It doesn't say how you want to handle interval end points. It also doesn't seem necessary to store the intervals as actual vectors as you do, but rather only the end points.

One implementation would be to simply subtract the interval end points one at a time from the integer. If one is negative and the other positive, it has to be in between them. If you want to be end point-inclusive, just allow one of the subtracted end points to equal zero.

```
intervals = list(interval.1=c(0, 10), interval.2=c(11,20), interval.3=c(-10, -1))

isbetween<-function(integer, intervals) {
  lapply(intervals, function(interval) {
    subtracted <- integer - interval
    isneg <- subtracted < 0
    # for inclusive end points, use <= instead of <
    result <- xor(isneg[1], isneg[2])
  })
}

>intervals[unlist(isbetween(5, intervals))]
$interval.1
[1]  0 10
```

You could then apply the result to the list of intervals to get the intervals and check that the sum of the result is <= 1 if it is important that no intervals are overlapping. Since the function doesn't need intervals to be ordered, you could just as well keep the interval vectors as objects in an env. If you have very long lists of intervals and know that they are not overlapping, you could put the same function logic in a while loop and break as soon as it finds the interval to not have to compute over the whole list of intervals. If you need to store your intervals as numeric vectors, just subset the first and last item in the subtraction.

Hope this helps!